# esri.tasks.PrintTask won't print WMS layers hosted by non-ESRI servers

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wms

I'm using the ESRI Javascript API. My esri.Map is successfully displaying WMS layers via esri.layers.WMSLayer. Some of the WMS layers are hosted by an ArcGIS Server and some are hosted by non-ESRI servers. But when I print using esri.tasks.PrintTask, only the WMS layers hosted by ArcGIS Server are visible. The WMS layers hosted by non-ESRI servers don't show up.

Has anyone succeeded in printing a WMS layer which is hosted by a non-ESRI server?

-Rick

Answer (score 1):

We test a wide variety of WMS sources internally at Esri for print services etc.  However, differing vendor support for the intricacies of WMS can be challenging sometimes. I suggest that you contact Esri technically support to log and issue with the particular service you are having issues with so it can be analyzed.